# Some database sanitzation questions

Tags: mysql, sanitization

we have a database of around ~250k records which we want to sanitize, and there are some queries which I just don't know how to write:

*clear words containing a substring, for example, if a word contains the substring "cache", delete the entire words, for example:

```
"cachelkjdlkjalkjs here happened something" => "here happend something"
```

*delete rows that include more than 2 digits, with exception of couple of cases, for example: the 3 digits 365 are permitted.

so:

```
"365 days a year, we do that" => Do nothing
"798 is a random number" => DELETE
```

*check for number of words, and delete records with less than X number of words.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL supports regular expressions in queries; that should give you the flexibility to do what you want - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: @Yobo MySQL regular expressions are unable to replace parts of the string.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a case for a programming language that connects to the database. It's not a job for mySQL alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First back up the database!

I would first draw up a list of words (along with the numbers 0...99, 365 and any others you think of). I would then create a script (language of yor chosing) to go through the rows. For each row retrieve the words, puncuation, and numbers and then check to ensure that they are valid. For the valid ones reconstruct the entry and spit out the bits that do not match. From the bits that do not match I would just have a look to ensure that you have not missed anything.

I would first do this in a passive mode (i.e. do not change the database) until you a happy that things are ok.

Hope that helps.